# How do i display a one to many relationship in Next js, supabase, typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, one-to-many, supabase

I am trying to display the car renovating projects where i have all the projects in one table: projecten, and i have the images with a description in another tabel: projecten_images. I related the images to the projecten through a foreign key. And i then use

```
const { data, error } = await supabase.from('projecten').select(`*, project_images(*)`)
```

to fetch the projecten and their images. But how can i display these images on a page of a specific car project.

Here is my database structure:
[Database structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVh9p.png)

This is the code i use for fetching the data with typescript:

```
import supabase from '../../utils/supabase';

export type Project = {
    id: string;
    merk: string;
    model: string;
    bouwjaar: string;
    beschrijvingkort: string;
    beschrijvinglang: string;
    images: string;
    alt_text: string;
    image_beschrijving: string;
    image_url: string;
    auto_naam: string;
    project_id: string;
}


const BASE_FILE_STORAGE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SUPABASE_BASE_FILE_URL;

export async function getAllProjecten(): Promise<Project[]> {

    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('projecten').select(`*, project_images(*)`)

    if (error) {
        throw error;
    }

    return data.map((project) => {
        return {
            id: project.id,
            merk: project.merk,
            model : project.model,
            bouwjaar : project.bouwjaar,
            beschrijvingkort : project.beschrijvingkort,
            beschrijvinglang : project.beschrijvinglang,
            images: BASE_FILE_STORAGE_URL + project.images,
            alt_text: project.alt_text,
            image_beschrijving: project.image_beschrijving,
            image_url: BASE_FILE_STORAGE_URL + project.image_url,
            auto_naam: project.auto_naam,
            project_id: project.project_id,
        }
    })
}

export async function getProject(name: string): Promise<Project | null> {
    return (await getAllProjecten()).find((project) => project.merk + project.model === name) || null
}
```

And this is how i am trying to display them on a specific [project] page in Next js

```
type Props = {
    project: Project;

}

export default function ProjectItem({ project }: Props) {
    return (
        <div className="bg-darkface">
            {/* Place header in */}
            <Header />
            {/* Main container margin and padding */}
            <main className="container mx-auto my-8 px-8 bg-graydisc rounded-md">
                <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row justify-between p-5 lg:p-20">
                    <div className="flex flex-col">
                        <h1 className="flex-start text-4xl lg:text-6xl font-bold text-blue">{project.merk + ' ' + project.model}</h1>
                        <p className="py-3 text-lg lg:text-xl w-[300px] lg:w-[500px]" >
                            {project.beschrijvinglang}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div className="relative w-[300px] h-[300px] sm:w-[400px] sm:h-[400px]">
                        <Image className="rounded-lg object-cover" src={project.images} alt='image' fill />
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-4">
                    {/* Band banner image */}
                    <div className="col-span-2 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-3 p-10">
                        {project.map(project => (
                            <div key={project.project_id} className="w-[250px] h-[250px] sm:w-[400px] sm:h-[400px] relative"> 
                                <Image
                                    className="rounded-lg object-cover"
                                    src={project.image_url}
                                    alt='image'
                                    fill
                                />
                            </div>
                          ))} 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            {/* Insert footer */}
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}

// Use function getstaticprops to retreive data from specific id
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps<Props> = async ({ params }) => {
    let project = await getProject(params?.project as string);
    project = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(project))
    // const project_images = await getProjectImages(params?.project_images as string);


    if (project == null) {
        return {
            notFound: true,
        }
    }

    return {
        props: { project},

    };
};

// Use function getstaticpath to point to the data file and retreive data
export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    const paths = (await getAllProjecten()).map(project => ({
        params: { project: project.merk + project.model },
    })) 

    return {
        paths,
        // fallback makes sure a 404 page appears when a path is not valid
        fallback: false
    };
};
```

Thank you for your help in advance. This is the first time i am posting a question on here so let me know if this enough or to little information to solve the problem.

I have tried to map the images but the images from the specific projects are not in an array. I am also not able to show the images without mapping them.